What package includes the rrsync command?
The rrsync command is the rsync server binary, called from ssh server when execute a rsync client command for a remote connection, but what package includes the rrsync command?
In my pc is located in:
$ which rrsync
/usr/bin/rrsync

I try search using apt search rrsync command but is not found, i try search un openssh and rsync .deb and .rpm package but is not found.
In official website https://rsync.samba.org/ says download from https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/ and the aarch64 package for centos 8 does not include the rrsync binary.
Does anyone know where i get the binary? I would like to use it by uploading the arm64 version to an Android device, chmod +x it, load dependencies using ldd and run it from an app that serves ssh so i can have a functional rsync server on my device and synchronize all the files from my terminal without extra applications.

Whoever builds the/an rsync binary package might need to enable it explicitly: https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/rsync/-/blob/main/PKGBUILD?ref_type=heads#L53

The rrsync utility is not a binary but a perl script. In my experience, rrsync is not installed by default. Typically, it's shipped as part of the standard rsync package as a file located somewhere under /usr/share/doc/rsync.
For exemple under Ubuntu 18.04:
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz
rsync: /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz

Or under RHEL9:
$ dnf whatprovides /usr/share/doc/rsync/support/rrsync
...
rsync-3.2.3-19.el9.x86_64 : A program for synchronizing files over a network
...
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/doc/rsync/support/rrsync

You then have to install it with a procedure looking like this:
cp /script/location/as/seen/above/rrsync.gz /usr/local/bin # Remove .gz extension under RHEL9
gunzip /usr/local/bin/rrsync.gz  # Not necessary under RHEL9 where it's not compressed
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rrsync
ln -s /usr/local/bin/rrsync /usr/bin

